# JS library for card sorting application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

Use case:
A web page where the user is presented with several cards containing text. The user can classify the cards by dragging them to one of four containers. The cards should then snap into place, and the container should display a counter with the number of cards it contains.

The app is based on Rails, but this obviuosly needs to be done in JavaScript. The content of the cards is read and written to the server through a JSON API.

I know basic JS, CSS and HTML 5, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction when it comes to implementing this. For instance:

- Should I use HTML 5 canvas?
- Is there a JS library that will make the implementation easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use make it without canvas, by using simple jQuery code.

Take a look at jQuery UI (https://jqueryui.com), especially at Draggable and Droppable.